# Jenkins maven plugin alters manifest

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-2

I am using Jenkins ver. 1.521 and standard maven plugin (ver 1.519) to build maven2 projects.

In manifest I can see entries I didn't configure in any of pom files:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: jenkins
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_45
Hudson-Build-Number: ...
Hudson-Project: ...
Hudson-Version: ...
Jenkins-Build-Number: ..
Jenkins-Project: ...
Jenkins-Version: ...
```

Where can I configure these entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I have found them hardcoded in [source of maven plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/maven/reporters/BuildInfoRecorder.java#L69) for jenkins, which is a sad thing.

Comment: If this question has been resolved, you should mark it answered, just to help those looking for help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any default behavior like that.  Typically this is configured in the build section of your pom.  Are you sure it isn't coming from an ancestor pom somewhere?

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
        </manifest>
        <manifestEntries>
          <Build-Job>${JOB_NAME}</Build-Job>
          <Build-Id>${BUILD_ID}</Build-Id>
          <Build-Number>${BUILD_NUMBER}</Build-Number>
          <Build-Repository-Rev>${SVN_REVISION}</Build-Repository-Rev>
          <Build-Time>${maven.build.timestamp}</Build-Time>
        </manifestEntries>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

In this example the child XML elements of `manifestEntries` are created based on the element names. Their can come from Maven properties, e.g. `maven.build.timestamp`, or environment variables, e.g. `JOB_NAME`.  The environment variables `JOB_NAME`, `BUILD_ID`, etc are [set by Jenkins when it executes the job](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables).

Comment: thank you for that. I have found them hardcoded in jenkins, but I will try to use your solution to override that.

Comment: @glaz666 Good catch - Now I'm confused why we don't see these entries in our MANIFESTs?  Perhaps the explicit configuration disables these default entries?  If you don't mind, post back what you find when you configure your entries.

Comment: I noticed this when I changed a project from using Maven 2.x to 3.x that the Hudson- and Jenkins- entries disappeared.